# RecyclerView output value to textview

Tags: android

I'm getting acquainted with the RecyclerView, I was able to implement when clicking on an item to display the position number. But I can't figure out how to write this id number in the EditText located on the activity

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_file_signature, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {

                    final FileInfoSignature fileInfo = values.get(position);                    
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), fileInfo.getFileName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    
//there is a mistake
                    EditText text =(EditText) parent.findViewById(R.id.etIntentsDataToSign);
                    text.setText(pathFile);

        return holder;
    }
```

my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/sf_list_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/Whitesmoke"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etIntentsDataToSign"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sf_list_data"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sf_list_data"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sf_list_data" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: you need to pass `listener` to your `activity` from adapter see this example
https://android.jlelse.eu/click-listener-for-recyclerview-adapter-2d17a6f6f6c9. and into activity set value to its edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more "acquainted". Here is a simple explanation. Your main layout contains a `RecyclerView` and an `EditText`. You initialize them both *inside their activity or fragment*:

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.sf_list_data);
editText = findViewById(R.id.etIntentsDataToSign);
// RecyclerView stuff here
// your edit text:
editText.setText("Hi world");
```

Likewise, a `RecyclerView`'s element/item , in your case it is `item_file_signature`. This item contains a `TextView` for example that can be initialized inside its adapter's `ViewHolder`:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
TextView itemTitle;
public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            itemTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
    }
}
```

Then inside onBindViewHolder:

```
viewHolder.itemTitle.setText("Hello World");
```

1. You do *not* need to check if a view is not an item of the recycler view because it clearly *isn't* and it is in a different layout file.
2. Even if you **do** initialize this edit text correctly, and your project compiles correctly, your app is doomed to force close due to a `NullPointerException`, clearly because like I already said it is not part of the adapter's layout file.

Edit: To pass the data from your adapter to the MainActivity, in your adapter create an onClickListener interface:

```
public interface myOnClickListener {
        
        void onRecyclerViewItemClicked(String text);
        
    }
```

Declare it as follows:

```
private myOnClickListener myClickListener;
```

And create a public method to be called from the MainActivity:

```
public void setMyOnClickListener(myOnClickListener myClickListener) {
        this.myClickListener =  myClickListener;
    }
```

In onBindViewHolder:

```
int itemPosition = getAdapterPosition();
final FileInfoSignature fileInfo = values.get(position);                    
                            
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (myClickListener != null) {                    
                            Toast.makeText( context , fileInfo.getFileName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            myOnClickListener.onRecyclerViewItemClicked(fileInfo.getFileName() );
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Finally, in your activity:

```
MainActivity implements YourAdapter.myOnClickListener
{
// after you initialize your adapter
adapter.setMyOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
    public void onRecyclerViewItemClicked(String text) {
        editText.setText ( text );
    }
```

Comment: As far as I understand in this way, we change the title of the selected item, but you cannot transfer this title to the EditText which is not in the RecyclerView?